# Any set E of real numbers with positive outer measure contains a subset that fails to be measurable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

The proof of Real Analysis by Royden starts: "by the countable subadditivity of outer measure, we may suppose E is bounded", I don't understand why the countable subadditivity of outer measure allows us to ignore the case in which E is not bounded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write $E$ as a countable union of bounded sets (say, $E\cap [-n,n]$ for eacn $n\in\mathbb{N}$).  If each of these bounded sets had outer measure $0$, then $E$ would have outer measure $0$, by countable subadditivity.  So one of these bounded sets has positive outer measure, and we can replace $E$ with such a set.